# C# split string with multiple separators

Tags: c#, split, delimiter

Strings:

```
string one = @"first%second";
string two = @"first%second%third";
string three = @"first%second%third%fourth";
```

I need to be able to separate everything that comes after the first '%' delimiter.
I'd normally use split function:

```
string partofstring = one.Split('%').Last();
```

or

```
string partofstring = one.Split('%').[1];
```

However I need to be able to get:

```
string oneresult = @"second";
string tworesult = @"second%third";
string threresult = @"second%third%fourth";
```

Comment: string.Join("%", one.Split('%').Skip(1))

Comment: `string two = @"first%second%third";
var result = two.Split(new[] { '%' }, 2).Last();`

Comment: `three.Split('%', 2)[1]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[string.Split has an overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Split_System_Char___System_Int32_) that allows you to specify the number of splits that you want to get back. Specifying 2 as the number of splits you will get an array with the element at index 0 that you can discard and the element at index 1 that is exactly the output requested

```
string three = @"first%second%third%fourth";
var result = three.Split(new char[] {'%'}, 2);
Console.WriteLine(result[1]); // ==> second%third%fourth
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
string partofstring = one.SubString(one.IndexOf('%'));
```

[String.SubString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8) returns a string starting from the specified position to the end of the string.

[String.IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.8) returns the first index of the specified character in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Either use a different overload of [`string.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Split_System_Char_System_Int32_System_StringSplitOptions_) that allows you to specify the maximum number of items:

```
var newString = myString.Split('%', 2)[1];
```

Note if you're using .NET Framework, you will need to use a different overload:

```
var newString = three.Split(new[] { '%'}, 2)[1];
```

Or, calculate it yourself using [`IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.8) and [`Substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8):

```
var newString = myString.Substring(myString.IndexOf('%') + 1);
```

Comment: the first result does not compile, this overload required Split(char[], int)

Comment: @styx Works fine if you're using .NET Core

Answer (score 0):

I've improved the code snippet given by @Preciousbetine

```
var partofstring = two.IndexOf('%') < 0 ? string.Empty : two.Substring(two.IndexOf('%') + 1);
```

This will check if the string doesn't contain the key %.